# Shopee redirect problem when using Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Am I the only one facing this issue? When I use the WebDriver to open the shopee URL, it will redirect me to the shopee login page, but when open the URL using my browser no redirection happened. The redirection causes me not able to scrape the data I want.

```
opsi = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
servis = Service('chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=servis, options=opsi)
shopee_link="https://shopee.com.my/--i.168085683.2848914120"
driver.get(shopee_link)
sleep(2)
content = driver.page_source
data = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
```

Is there any way I can do to prevent the redirection happen? Or it is Shopee purposely make it like that?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this argument in options:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
```

use with precaution: it sends info of your system to de server

I am also simulating mouse moves, mouse clicks and scrolling.
ie.:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'main')
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()    

# scroll to load products
for i in range(50):
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 100)")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except:
        break
```

I also created an account and I am logging on it before scrap the site

And... last but not least, when I send info to the input fields I do not send keys at once.

```
pass_field= driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pDzPRp')[1]
actions.move_to_element(pass_field).click().perform()
for i in password:
    pass_field.send_keys(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I consider shoppe is the most challenging platform to extract info so now. Good Luck for you